# Set of left cosets = set of right cosets implies normal

Tags: group-theory, quotient-group

Let $G$ be a group, $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Define

$G/H := \{~gH~|~g \in G~\}$

$H\backslash G := \{~Hg~|~g \in G~\}$.

I want to show $G/H=H\backslash G$ implies $H\unlhd G$:

Assume $G/H=H\backslash G$. Then $\forall g\in G, g\in gH$, where $gH = Hg'$ for some $g'\in G$. So $g\in Hg'$ for some $g'\in G$. Hence $g=hg'$ for some $h\in H$. So $gH = Hg' = Hh^{-1}g = Hg$, and $H$ is therefore normal in $G$.

I feel very strange about this, could anyone help me check whether it is correct?

Comment: $g = hg'$ should get you $h^{-1}g = g'$, reverse from what you have right now. But that should allow you to conclude that $gH = Hg$.

Comment: @MyGlasses $gH$ depends upon $g$; it's not constant over all $g \in G$.

Comment: @platty Yes, you are right. It is updated, thank you very much!

Comment: Looks right to me.

Answer (score 3):

Your argument is ok but perhaps this one is simpler:

The left cosets form a partition of $G$. So do the right cosets.

If $gH$ is a right coset, then it must be $Hg$ because that's the only one that contains $g$.